# Query replace with different replacements

Tags: query-replace

Suppose we start with the following

```
Adam ate an apple. 

Adam ate an apple.

Adam ate an apple.

Adam ate an apple.

Adam ate an apple.
```

I want to replace `Adam` with `Bob`, `Chris`, and `David`. So I want to do it such that I call a `query-replace`-like function, search for `Adam` and then cycle through the results specifying what to replace it by.

I am guessing there are three possible answers here:

1. Write a function to do it, which I haven't tried.
2. There is a way to do it using `query-replace`-like function which is what I am looking for.
3. I realize that I could do `C-r` during `query-replace`, but I was wondering if there was a way to avoid that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming `Bob` is the first replacement:

- <kbd>M-%</kbd> `Adam` <kbd>RET</kbd> `Bob` <kbd>RET</kbd>
- <kbd>y</kbd> for all the consecutive `Bob` replacements
- <kbd>e</kbd> to change the replacement string, to, e.g.: `Chris` <kbd>RET</kbd>
- <kbd>y</kbd> for any further `Chris` replacements
- etc...
- When you want to re-use one of the previous replacements (say, `Adam` again)
- <kbd>e</kbd> and then <kbd>M-p</kbd> or <kbd><up></kbd> to cycle back through the replacement history